# Create FileMaker invoice plugin

Tags: plugins, filemaker

I'm not a FileMaker expert so as specific answers as possible would be appreciated. I need to create a plugin that exports specific database fields from a FileMaker 9 application and then creates a document from that data. Think about an invoice document that has your own data, clients data and product or hours that the client needs to pay for. The final goal is to export the data into an editor where the user can tweak everything and add text to it.

Comment: Why do you think a plugin is required for this task? What feature do you need that the native export cannot provide?

Comment: The goal is to export an invoice (I assume you can create a template and just fill the data there) with extra content. So see it as an editable (in application) document that contains an invoice. Does this make sense?

Comment: "*Does this make sense?*" I am afraid not. Do you know *anything* about Filemaker?

Comment: No, not really. I need to modify an existing application. The current version has this function already build in but you can't modify the outcome and there is a problem with the layout.

Comment: I am afraid I don't know how to answer this, because you are not explaining the problem in terms I can understand, and you wouldn't be able to understand my answer if I did. **Filemaker is not an intuitive application**. You won't be able to modify an existing application, if you don't have at least basic FM skills. You will, however, be able to do plenty of damage.

Comment: Yeah, I was already afraid of that. What kind of level of FM knowledge would you need to have for such a task? I maybe don't have knowledge of FileMaker and it's 4GL alternatives, but I do have programming experience and that's why my first idea was to make a plugin.

Comment: At minimum, do the tutorial that came with the application. That will bring you to a level where you will at least know how to ask questions. I would suggest you join one of  Filemaker-specific forums for that, as this is more about using the application than actual programming (Filemaker is rather a hybrid beast, when it comes to that). -- Hint: you won't be needing to write a plugin.

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna try to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, so far it doesn't sound like you need a plugin, although we would need more information to be sure.

What I *think* you want to do is copy existing FileMaker data to another application. You say "The final goal is to export the data into an editor..." Which begs the question, why does the data have to be edited in an editor and not within FileMaker itself, either via the FileMaker Pro client or via a web application using the PHP API?

Assuming you *do* need this external editor for some reason, FileMaker can almost certainly export the data in some format that the external editor can work with (CSV, XML, HTML, whatever).

If the reason you're thinking of using the external editor is for security purposes, that can be handled with permissions in FileMaker.

Comment: I'm trying to do it without external application help. The idea is/was to do the following. Export invoice data to an application and make it style the data into a decent invoice document (the current FM application does this into pdf but has a product row problems with empty rows). This invoice document editor should be able to edit/add/remove text in that specific document. As an example: first page could be a letter or information, second page the invoice, third and fourth page the EULA and all of this could be edited by the client how ever he/she wants.

Comment: I think you can do everything you want and remain in FileMaker. Do the clients have access to FileMaker via FileMaker Pro or a web application? If the problem with FileMaker is that it's retaining unneeded empty rows, that can be handled with scripting by omitting them from the found set or, perhaps, with layout settings, by having them slide up. While FileMaker certainly has weaknesses in a number of areas, this doesn't sound like one of those areas.

Comment: See my profile with my Twitter handle if you'd like to discuss offsite.